# How to run a quartz trigger in my local server in clustered environment

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler

multiple servers are running on same database with same quartz.properties file.
but there is a requirement (for debugging purpose) where i want to trigger my jobs (created from my server) specifically on my server.

i tried changing org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName but it didn't work, jobs are still triggering on random machines.

Is there any way by which i can trigger job on my server which were configured by my server.

```
**my quartz properties**
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = myLocalInstance
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

** all other server instance Quartz properties **
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = commonInstance
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
```

Comment: Jobs created on commonInstance will continue to be invoked by random instances. Can you create a new job after you change to 'myLocalInstance' ? They will be triggered only in your local server..can you test that?

Comment: @Srinivas yes i am able to create a new job, but it is still running on randomly to any instance of server pointing to same DB.

Comment: Interesting. Can you look at qrtz tables ( QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE,  QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS, QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS, QRTZ_TRIGGERS) and make sure data there is as per your expectation.  You should be seeing entries for your new local instance.

Comment: @JitendraYadav Quartz docs says that `Never fire-up a non-clustered instance against the same set of tables that any other instance is running against. You may get serious data corruption, and will definitely experience erratic behavior.`,maybe try to use different `tablePrefix`.

Comment: @yishaiz changing instanceName would make my scheduler instance to non-clustered ? 
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true set in properties..

Comment: you didn't post full properties files so its hard to understand - in which one did you set `isClustered=true`? separate `instanceName` should run as a separate scheduler.  You can try the different `tablePrefix` as I said, maybe it will help. And if you will post full properties files (the 2 different files) it may be helpful.